# Use cases - for vs for_each in terraform - struggling to visualise

Tags: for-loop, terraform

Is the `for` expression in Terraform basically just to provide more granular control on a `for_each` meta argument, so maybe it just iterates on a subset of a list, for example?

The difference between `for_each` and `count` is clear enough. I am just a bit lost trying to visualise the point of the `for`

Many thanks for any pointers, including articles. Google isn't proving that helpful

Answer (score 3):

In Terraform `for` and `for_each` are used for different purposes.

`for_each` is a meta-argument. It is applied to resources and to modules (Terraform 0.13 and above). `for_each` meta-arguments accepts a set or a map, for every item from the set/map a new resource is created.

For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  for_each = {
    "t2.micro" = "ami-b374d5a5"
    "t3.nano"  = "ami-4b32be2b"
  }

  instance_type = each.key
  ami           = each.value
}
```

This will create 2 EC2 instances with instance types and AMIs from the map. Please note, `for_each` provides `each.key` and `each.value` objects which can be used when iterating through the map to reference its key-value items. If the input of a `for_each` is a set, than `each.key` and `each.value` are pointing to the same value.

`for`, in the other hand, is an expression used to manipulate lists, sets, tuples and maps. It can be used to apply some transformations to the elements of those complex types.

For example:

```
variable "names" {
  default = ["alice", "bob"]
}

locals {
  upper = [for n in names: upper(n)] # result will be ["ALICE", "BOB"]
}
```

The ouput of a `for` expression can be used as input for a `for_each`.

Example:

```
var ids {
 default = ["b374d5a5", "4b32be2b"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  for_each = toset([for id in ids: "ami-${id}"])

  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami           = each.value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, answering my own Q..

Seems to be helpful to apply a function to a list,etc that is being iterated in a resource e.g. changing case, converting variable type, decoding from base64, etc